# Working out Conditional Probability of 3 prize,winners

Tags: probability

> There are $24$ prizes, on offer for $24$ winners. There are $4$ cars, $8$ bikes and $12$ watches. Friends $A,B,C$ win $3$ of the prizes. If the $3$ prizes ate drawn at random
>
> What is probability that:
>
> **a)** Both $A$ and $B$ get cars given $C$ gets a car
>
> **b)** $A$ gets a car given $B$ gets either a car or a bicycle.

I'm getting the right answer but not using

$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$$

Cannot work out numerator in which probabilities I should use.

The answers, if you're interested are:

**a)** $\large \frac{3}{253}$

**c)** $\large \frac{11}{138}$

Bruce

Answer (score 2):

**a)** Both $A$ and $B$ get cars given $C$ gets a car

$P(C_{car}) = \frac{4}{24} = \frac{1}{6} $

Because the car isn't replaced:

$P(B_{car}) = \frac{3}{23}$

$P(A_{car}) = \frac{2}{22}$

$P(A_{car}B_{car}|C_{car}) = \frac{P(A_{car}B_{car}C_{car})}{P(C_{car})}$

$= P(A_{car}B_{car}) = \frac{3}{253}$